# Custom DataGridView duplicated columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've created a custom Winforms control by subclassing from the DataGridView.

The custom datagrid view defines it's own columns and mappings.

However whenever I drag it off the toolbox and onto the design surface of a form, the form recreates a column control (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn) for each column in the custom control, such that I end up with double the number of columns I should have.

The whole idea is that the control is already "self aware" so I don't need the form to do anything. Clearly I've overlooked something simple but I'm more Web than Windows and nothing immediately stands out as the cause for this.

[image]

Custom Datagrid:

```
 partial class StrategyGrid
{
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle13 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle14 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle15 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle16 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle17 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle18 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle19 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle20 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle21 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle22 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle23 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle24 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xTargetNetProfitAmt = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xTargetNetProfitPct = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.xColumn2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.bindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
            dataGridViewCellStyle13.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle13;
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Qty";
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 85;
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 85;
            // 
            // zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "BuyPricePerShare";
            dataGridViewCellStyle14.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle14.Format = "N2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle14.NullValue = null;
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle14;
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Buy Price";
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 85;
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToolTipText = "Buy price per share";
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 85;
            // 
            // zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "BuyParcelSubtotal";
            dataGridViewCellStyle15.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle15.Format = "C2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle15.NullValue = null;
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle15;
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Buy Sub";
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 85;
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = false;
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 85;
            // 
            // zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "BuyBrokerageFeeAmount";
            dataGridViewCellStyle16.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle16.Format = "C0";
            dataGridViewCellStyle16.NullValue = null;
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle16;
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Rates";
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 75;
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToolTipText = "Buy Brokerage Rates";
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = false;
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 75;
            // 
            // xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "BuyParcelTotal";
            dataGridViewCellStyle17.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle17.Format = "N0";
            dataGridViewCellStyle17.NullValue = null;
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle17;
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Buy Price Total";
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 85;
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToolTipText = "Buy Total Parcel Cost";
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 85;
            // 
            // xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "BreakevenPricePerShare";
            dataGridViewCellStyle18.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle18.Format = "N2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle18.NullValue = null;
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle18;
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "B/E Price";
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 100;
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToolTipText = "Breakeven price per share";
            // 
            // xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "TargetPricePerShare";
            dataGridViewCellStyle19.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle19.Format = "N2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle19.NullValue = null;
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle19;
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Target Price";
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 100;
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToolTipText = "Target price per share";
            // 
            // xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            // 
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "TargetParcelTotal";
            dataGridViewCellStyle20.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle20.Format = "N0";
            dataGridViewCellStyle20.NullValue = null;
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle20;
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Target Price NV";
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.MinimumWidth = 100;
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ToolTipText = "Target Price Net Value";
            // 
            // xTargetNetProfitAmt
            // 
            this.xTargetNetProfitAmt.DataPropertyName = "TargetNetProfitAmt";
            dataGridViewCellStyle21.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle21.Format = "N2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle21.NullValue = "0";
            this.xTargetNetProfitAmt.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle21;
            this.xTargetNetProfitAmt.HeaderText = "Target NP Amt";
            this.xTargetNetProfitAmt.MinimumWidth = 100;
            this.xTargetNetProfitAmt.Name = "xTargetNetProfitAmt";
            // 
            // xTargetNetProfitPct
            // 
            this.xTargetNetProfitPct.DataPropertyName = "TargetNetProfitPct";
            dataGridViewCellStyle22.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            this.xTargetNetProfitPct.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle22;
            this.xTargetNetProfitPct.HeaderText = "Target NP Pct";
            this.xTargetNetProfitPct.MinimumWidth = 100;
            this.xTargetNetProfitPct.Name = "xTargetNetProfitPct";
            // 
            // xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt
            // 
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt.DataPropertyName = "MarketPriceNetProfitAmt";
            dataGridViewCellStyle23.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle23.Format = "N2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle23.NullValue = "0";
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle23;
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt.HeaderText = "Market Price NP Amt";
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt.MinimumWidth = 100;
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt.Name = "xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt";
            // 
            // xMarketPriceNetProfitPct
            // 
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct.DataPropertyName = "MarketPriceNetProfitPct";
            dataGridViewCellStyle24.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle24.Format = "N2";
            dataGridViewCellStyle24.NullValue = null;
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle24;
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct.HeaderText = "Market Price NP Pct";
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct.MinimumWidth = 100;
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct.Name = "xMarketPriceNetProfitPct";
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // xColumn2
            // 
            this.xColumn2.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            this.xColumn2.HeaderText = "";
            this.xColumn2.Name = "xColumn2";
            this.xColumn2.ReadOnly = true;
            // 
            // bindingSource1
            // 
            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(FlatShareTradePlanList);
            // 
            // StrategyGrid
            // 
            this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
            this.xTargetNetProfitAmt,
            this.xTargetNetProfitPct,
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt,
            this.xMarketPriceNetProfitPct,
            this.xColumn2});
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.MultiSelect = false;
            this.Name = "StrategyGridView";
            this.RowHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Sunken;
            this.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1193, 401);
            this.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.entryStrategyGridView_CellFormatting);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn zquantityDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn zbuyPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn zbuyParcelSubtotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn zbuyBrokerageFeeAmountDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xbuyParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xbreakevenPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xtargetPricePerShareDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xtargetParcelTotalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xTargetNetProfitAmt;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xTargetNetProfitPct;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xMarketPriceNetProfitAmt;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xMarketPriceNetProfitPct;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn xColumn2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1;


    }
```

When dragging onto a form the form generates the following insides it's InitializeComponent:

```
  private StrategyGrid strategyGrid1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn7;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn8;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn10;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn11;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn12;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn13;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn14;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn15;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn28;
```

Not sure where it's reading this "requirement" of having these columns from... but it's wrong. They are already present within the custom control. I thought maybe something to do AccessModifiers but can't seem to work it out.

Comment: Code would help please...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a code dump right off the bat as it's designer generated and thus ugly and verbose. I'm hoping  it's something obvious to a WinForms dev.... but if you insist...

Comment: Can you set DataGridViewAutoGenerateColumns to false?

Comment: That was my first thought but it changes nothing. Also note this behaviour is design time. So no data is being pumped into the control.

Comment: ONLY at design time or at runtime as well? Can you do a count of your columns at runtime and see what that produces?

Comment: Oh the columns are duplicated at both runtime and design time. But they show up in design prior to any data being added as the data source. My understanding is AutogenerateColumns property takes effect when a data source is applied. But this is happening prior to a datasource being applied. It's almost like the Forms designer is using some type of reflection.... but not sure what's triggering it. So the graphic above re: Starts again is consistent across both design and run times.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. I will look into this, has me kind of stumped as well.

Comment: @rism were you able to solve this? If so kindly post the solution. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have not assigned Column's `DataPropertyName` in those columns. if you have created columns manually and assigning DataSrouce to the data grid the unmatched column will be generated automatically. Get more information and example about `DataPropertyName` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you look at the code I posted you can see I have assigned DataPropertyName

Comment: then might be it doesn't match with your sql query fields.

Answer (score 2):

go to **gridview** properties or F4 --> Uncheck Auto Generated Coloumns ="False"

Answer (score 0):

If you have code like that ;

```
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                GridName.Columns.Add(columnNames[i], columnNames[i]);
            }
```

add each column just one time. I used a flag

```
        if (AddColumnFlag)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                GridName.Columns.Add(columnNames[i], columnNames[i]);
            }
        }
```

and when I call the function anywhere apart from constructor, set flag to false.
It's solved my problem.