# CustomDataGridView Produces Duplicate Columns in Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

My question is exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794309/custom-datagridview-duplicated-columns?rq=1) Pls. don't down vote as the thread did not have answers.

Problem in Brief:
I have an CustomGridView, a type of DataGridView. The below code is attached to it. When I drop the datagridview in design time I can see the columns are all in proper but except for the name of the datagridviewcolumn names are different and is not what I gave.

[image]

In runtime the Columns are duplicated. Could not figure out why.

[image]

Property Page looks like this

[image]

Code:

```
public class CustomAccountDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        private bool _paddingOn = true;

        public bool PaddingOn
        {
            get { return _paddingOn; }
            set { _paddingOn = value; }
        }

        public CustomAccountDataGridView()
        {
            this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.Columns.Clear();

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnAccountID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            columnAccountID.DataPropertyName = "ACCOUNTID";
            columnAccountID.Name = "colACCOUNTID";
            columnAccountID.HeaderText = "A/c";
            columnAccountID.Width = 110;
            columnAccountID.Visible = false;
            this.Columns.Add(columnAccountID);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnClientAccountID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            columnClientAccountID.DataPropertyName = "CLIENTACCOUNTID";
            columnClientAccountID.Name = "colCLIENTACCOUNTID";
            columnClientAccountID.HeaderText = "Client A/c";
            columnClientAccountID.Width = 110;
            this.Columns.Add(columnClientAccountID);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnParticipantID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            columnParticipantID.DataPropertyName = "PARTICIPANTID";
            columnParticipantID.Name = "colPARTICIPANTID";
            columnParticipantID.HeaderText = "Participant";
            columnParticipantID.Width = 60;
            this.Columns.Add(columnParticipantID);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnAccountName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            columnAccountName.Name = "colACCOUNTNAME";
            columnAccountName.HeaderText = "A/c Name";
            columnAccountName.Width = 200;
            columnAccountName.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Columns.Add(columnAccountName);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnXsactValue = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            columnXsactValue.DataPropertyName = "XSACTVALUE";
            columnXsactValue.Name = "colXSACTVALUE";
            columnXsactValue.Width = 110;
            columnXsactValue.HeaderText = "Value";
            columnXsactValue.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            columnXsactValue.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            this.Columns.Add(columnXsactValue);
        }

        protected override void OnDataBindingComplete(DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            string sClientID = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dvr in (this.Rows))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dvr.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (this.Columns[i].DataPropertyName == "ACCOUNTID")
                    {
                        if (dvr.Cells["colACCOUNTID"].Value != null)
                        {
                            sClientID = dvr.Cells["colACCOUNTID"].Value.ToString();
                            dvr.Cells["colACCOUNTNAME"].Value = sClientID; //utility.ClientExtention.getAccountName(sClientID);

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnDataBindingComplete(e);
        }

        protected override void OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
            {
                (e.Control as TextBox).CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
            }

            base.OnEditingControlShowing(e);
        }

        protected override void OnCellValueChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string sClientAccountID = string.Empty;
            string sParticipantID = "JKB";

            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (this.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "CLIENTACCOUNTID")
                {
                    if (this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
                    {
                        if (this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                        {
                            if (this.PaddingOn)
                            {
                                sClientAccountID = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper().PadLeft(13, '0');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sClientAccountID = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
                            }

                            this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = sClientAccountID;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (this.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "PARTICIPANTID")
                {
                    if (this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
                    {
                        if (this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                        {

                            sParticipantID = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().ToUpper();
                        }

                        this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = sParticipantID;
                    }
                }

                if (sClientAccountID != string.Empty & sParticipantID != string.Empty)
                {
                    this["ACCOUNTNAME", e.RowIndex].Value = (string.Format("{0}-{1}", sParticipantID, sClientAccountID));
                }

            }

            base.OnCellValueChanged(e);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where you call `InitializeComponent()` method? If method was called after line `this.Columns.Clear();`, then on runtime, columns which was created in designer, will be added to already created columns in constructor.

Comment: @Fabio, I don't write an `InitializeComponent()` method. I add a class item to the project and overwrite its content to this. That's what I was doing.

Comment: Your class inherited from `DataGridView` class which has this method. Did you call base constructor some where?

Comment: @Fabio I have not called it any where.

Comment: So I see only reason: you have created columns in designer, then you created same columns in code. So I think columns created in designer added after you create columns with code

Comment: Comment code in constructor after line `this.Columns.Clear();` and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I found something that seems to work [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/667354ed-d426-4ac0-a6db-73aa1c474a6d/datagridview-duplicated-columns-issue-whats-the-fixworkaround?forum=winformsdatacontrols):

```
protected override void InitLayout()
    {
        base.InitLayout();
        SetColumns();
    }
```

SetColumns is the subroutine to add the columns I want.

Answer (score 0):

In case it can be helpful, I have just encountered this problem, on VS 2015 Express, with a standard DataGridView. The problem appeared as soon as I renamed my custom columns. Reverting to default names fixed the problem, as much as flushing the custom columns and keeping the duplicates. I can reproduce and fix the problem anytime, it seems consistent. Note that when both original and duplicate columns are in, there is no trace of the duplicates in the designer code(Designer.cs), don't ask me why...